# Changing font at run-time

Tags: c#, winforms

Looking at some old VB 6.0 code we had created a global mFont variable and on Form_Load we had said **richTextbox.Font = mFont**,  then later in code that there is a toolbar button to increase the font size we had just increased the size but did not have to do richTextbox.Font = mFont  one more time. It was just doing it, but looks like in C# is it different? each time I change that font size do I have to assign it again so it takes effect?  ( assuming still I have assgined richTextBox.Font = mFont at Form_Load event )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the properties in Font are only settable through the constructor, you would need to create a new Font instance and reassign that to the RTB.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is correct.  You need to set the Font property to a new Font object whenever you want to change any aspect of the font.